# Combine Multiple rows with same value

Tags: php, laravel-5

im trying to make like

```
id  name    qty
1   item a   3
2   item b   9 
3   item c   7
```

from

```
id  name    qty
1   item a   1
1   item a   2
2   item b   3 
2   item b   1 
2   item b   5
3   item c   3
3   item c   4
```

by using codes like this

```
$recapout = DB::table('tb_itemsout')
->select(DB::raw('sum(tb_itemsout.qty) as qty'),'tb_itemsout.id','tb_master_item.item_name','tb_itemsout.qty')
->groupBy('tb_itemsout.','tb_master_item.item_name','tb_itemsout.qty')
->join('tb_master_item','tb_itemsout.id','tb_master_item.id')
->orderBy('tb_master_item.id_item','DESC')
->get();
```

but it doesnt seem to work. it keeps shows up like

this

```
id  name    qty
1   item a   1
1   item a   2
2   item b   3 
2   item b   1 
2   item b   5
3   item c   3
3   item c   4
```

Comment: `SELECT sum(qty),name from item_table GROUP by name`
why are your using join in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove qty field from your GroupBy function. it doesn't fulfill your needs by grouping of qty.

```
$recapout = DB::table('tb_itemsout')
->select(DB::raw('sum(tb_itemsout.qty) as qty'),'tb_itemsout.id','tb_master_item.item_name','tb_itemsout.qty')
->groupBy('tb_itemsout.','tb_master_item.item_name')    // remove tb_itemsout.qty
->join('tb_master_item','tb_itemsout.id','tb_master_item.id')
->orderBy('tb_master_item.id_item','DESC')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel query does not seem to line up with the data you showed us.  Going by the data itself, you seem to want:

```
$recapout = DB::table('tb_itemsout AS out')
    ->select('out.id', 'item.item_name', DB::raw('SUM(out.qty) AS qty'))
    ->groupBy('out.id', 'item.item_name')
    ->join('tb_master_item AS item', 'out.id', 'item.id')
    ->orderBy('out.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

This would correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT out.id, item.item_name, SUM(out.qty) AS qty
FROM tb_itemsout out
INNER JOIN tb_master_item item
    ON item.id = out.id
GROUP BY
    outbid, item.item_name
ORDER BY
    out.id DESC;
```